# Get the element which has class active?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a list. I want to get the element of the id which has class active.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav">
   <li class="active" id="day" onclick="changeDur('day')"><a data-toggle="tab">Day</a></li>
   <li id="week" onclick="changeDur('week')"><a data-toggle="tab">Week</a></li>
   <li id="month" onclick="changeDur('month')"><a data-toggle="tab">Month</a></li>
   <li id="year" onclick="changeDur('year')"><a data-toggle="tab">Year</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here's what I'm trying?

```
var period_val = $("#nav.active").attr('id');
alert(period_val)
```

It gives me `undefined`.

Where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var period_val = $("#nav .active").attr('id');
```

You need a space to select descendent elements.

Comment: Thanks. A simple mistake.

Answer (score 4):

`var period_val = $("#nav .active").attr('id');` - needs a space after "#nav", otherwise you're looking for an UL which has id "nav" and class "active"

A child selector, as mentioned above would do as well.

Just to make my post a bit more usefull here are the links:

[CSS selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

[Additional jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) `>`:

```
   var period_val = $("#nav > .active").attr("id");
```